# HTML button redirects to page and select one checkbox in form?

Tags: html, forms, button

I'm creating a website for a hotel and I'm trying to create a button for each house you can book and for each house is a button, which opens the booking page. And my question is , how to do that my button redirects me to the page and selects the houses checkbox. For example i click on the button in the G-house's div and it selects the G-house's checkbox.

The part of the html page where the button is:

```
                        <img src="pics/csecsilak_01.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="nyaralok-text-content">
                            <h2>G épület</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <button type=button">Book</button>
                        </div>
```

And the part of the booking page`s form:

```
                        <label class="main-label" for="nyaralo">Nyaraló:</label>
                        <div class="g-epulet-checkbox">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            <input class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" name="g-epulet" value="g-epulet">
                            <label>G épület</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="e-epulet-checkbox">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            <input class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" id="e-epulet" name="e-epulet" value="e-epulet">
                            <label>E épület</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="v-epulet-checkbox">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                            <input class="checkbox-custom" type="checkbox" id="v-epulet" name="v-epulet" value="v-epulet">
                            <label>V épület</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Thanks if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sooner or later you're going to have to use JavaScript or server side programming. In this case the easiest solution would probably be to append a HTTP GET parameter to the URL (like `?type=x&param=y`) which is automatically done by HTML `form` with `method="GET"`. Then use PHP to generate the other form or tick the box via JavaScript. The latter is probably preferable.